50meter CAT5 Trig Echo HC-SR04 Arduino L7805 not getting a distance reading other than zero
I had an Arduino sending 5V to a HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor. My code was working just fine when I had it all wired up with cabling <4-5 inches long between the Arduino and the sensor.  Confident with my code seeing as it was working fine and I was getting accurate distance measurements on the serial monitor every 500 milliseconds.
I set out to deploy my ultrasonic sensor 50 meters away from my Arduino to sense the water level in a tank.  I chose a 50 meter CAT5 cable in hopes that the cable would help with long distance.  To ensure 5V was being supplied to the sensor end, I stopped my Arduino being my 5V supply and added a 12 volt battery with an L7805 5 volt voltage regulator on the sensor end.  Using a multi-meter I made sure I am getting 5V on the sensor end.
Now I have my trig (RX) and my echo (TX) wired to the CAT5 50 meter cable on the sensor end and on the Arduino end I have it soldered to the same digital INPUT and OUTPUT pins 8 & 7 as I had originally wired when trying proof of concept.
I am not real sure why with the addition of 50 meter length between the Arduino sensor I am no longer registering a distance reading. All I get back is a solid zero now every 500 milliseconds.
Really trying to figure out if an input capacitor and output capacitor soldered between the 5V L7805 will help with the voltage being sent to the sensor. If my voltage is fine then do I need to add something to the trig(RX) and echo(TX) on either sensor end or Arduino end?  Is RS485 the only answer to long distance cabling?

Did you connect GND as well?

The L7805 GND should also be connected through that long cable back to arduino GND.

Welcome! Please draw a block diagram. Where did you connect your 7805? How is the sensor powered? How is the Arduino powered? What does the signal look like on your oscilloscope? What is used for ground reference on both sides of the cable?

Is the logic level at 3.3 or 5V?

Using logic level signals between chips via 50 meter cable is not going to work, not even if cable is CAT5.
The DC resistance is about 9 ohms per each wire. There is no number how much the sensor draws when idle or active, but even 100mA pulse can cause 0.9V drop or difference in the ground wire.
It causes problems both in supplt voltage and data transmission.
The 7805 obviously needs capacitors on input and output or it will be unstable.
The final issue is logic level signals being sent on CAT5. It is a 100 ohm transmission line. It takes 250 nanoseconds for a signal to travel 50 meters. During that time the wire looks like a 100 ohm load. It's 50mA with 5V logic levels or 33mA with 3.3V logic levels. The IO pins are not intended to drive such loads. The transmission lines are unterminated so there will be ringing and reflections as a signal edge bounces back between unterminated high impedance input end and driven low impedance output end. It takes several times of 250ns travel time back and forth before reflections die out.
In short, do not put a 50 metet piece of CAT5 between two logic ICs and expect it to work.
Even RS-422 or RS-485 would work because it allows for +/- 7V difference between grounds at each end of the cable so a bit more than 500mA of DC current on one ground return wire, and it will force you to terminate the differential pairs into 120 ohms. Which is not even the correct value for CAT5 but should be adequate.
Without RS-4xx it is possible but it takes a lot of time and effort to even pass the data with e.g. terminated bus and schmitt triggers while keeping the ground current in limits so the ground bounce voltage is not too high via wire resistance and the fed supply current. Maybe an isolated 12V to 5V module on two separate wires.

The problem is not current-limiting of 5.5 or 3.6V CMOS logic to CAT 5 but ringing from reflections of mismatched impedances.
Given Data from the ATmega Datasheet p259
For VCC=5V:
Iol=20 mA, Vol max=0.8 V
Zo max = Vol max/Iol = 0.8/20m = 40 Ω
The typical output impedance is approximately 50% of the max. so adding 22 ohms min to 50 improves the results.
But the unlisted spec that causes ringing on long cables is Zo min.
For VCC=3V: Iol=5 mA, Vol max = 0.5 V
Zo max = Vol max/Iol = 0.5V/5mA = 100 Ω
The typical and minimum values would be Zo ≈ 50 Ω typ
Importance of Zo​ Matching
A mismatch between Zo and the cable’s characteristic impedance (100Ω for CAT5) can cause ringing and reflections.  Adding a 25Ω–50Ω series resistor increases the driver’s effective impedance, reducing these effects.
Reflections and Terminations
Termination at the Receiver End
A resistor (e.g., 100 Ω) reduces reflections but introduces attenuation.  Using an active termination (biasing to VDD/2) can improve signal integrity by adding offset to match the input mean threshold while preventing no load reflections.  It doesn't have to be perfectly matched at these speeds but reducing attenuation also helps with a biased termination.
Attenuation Factor
For a CAT5 cable with 8~10Ω per wire @ 50m adds attenuation:
With Rterm=100 Ω, the attenuation factor is:
\$V_{out}=V_{in}\frac{R_{term}}{R_{term}+Z_{cable}+Z_{source}}\$
Conclusion
The suggested Rs=25 to 50 Ω at the source is effective for this driver-cable configuration. It reduces reflections and ringing while maintaining adequate signal strength.
Active termination at the receiver improves performance further in both directions.
I simulated with ideal switches and various combinations I have used in the past that work to verify the results for you here. (in slow motion)


